# Can I continue to work with "Object data type instead of changing it back to string or int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

What's the effects of working with columns whose Data type is showing object instead of string, int etc?

Should I expect errors if I decide to continue without changing the type?

I tried performing operations on the columns and am getting errors, I'm beginning to suspect the d-type

Comment: if there are numerical calculations you need to change the data type from object to `int` or `float`. If it involves just `string` ;`object` data type will be fine.

Comment: Check this out: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-convert-column-to-int/

Comment: "*I tried performing operations on the columns and am getting errors*" -> which exact operations? On which data? Giving which error? We can't answer a question without specifics and a reproducible example.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Thanks God Is One, your answer was helpful